# Spring boot multiple params - GET request

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am facing a DB2 issue while passing multiple params from FE. Initially i tried to pass one parameter from FE and 2nd parameter I gave directly in query itself, then it was working fine. But now I'm trying to pass both parameters from FE and now getting DB issue. 
And i checked in service both parameters are coming to BE, But not getting any idea what is the issue.

This is my controller:

```js
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
@CrossOrigin
public class AController {
@RequestMapping(value = "search/{keyword}/{nrows}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public BOutput readId(@PathVariable("keyword") String keyword, @PathVariable("nrows") int nrows) {
  return aService.findId(keyword, nrows);
  }
}
```

This is Repository Interface:

```js
@Repository
public interface Udata_Repository  extends JpaRepository<UTable, String>  {

@Query(value = "select B_ID from UTable where B_ID like :keyword% FETCH FIRST :nrows ROWS ONLY", 
nativeQuery=true)
List<String> find_id(@Param("keyword") String keyword, @Param("nrows") int nrows);
}
```

My FE GET request is like this:

```js
http://localhost:8080/api/auth/search/A/1
```

This is the error which I'm getting in spring boot console.
[image]

I tried to checked all possible ways but not getting solved this, need some help here.

Comment: @HadiJ Request is same only right, like you suggested. you mean to remove this method = RequestMethod.GET ?

Comment: I don't think you can put a parameter on the `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` statement.

Comment: @LorisSecuro I'm not sure we can put n as a parameter or not, but before I gave value directly there instead of parameter..and that time it was working fine.

Comment: @LorisSecuro But technically we can pass right and there is no such rules right?

Comment: Try to log your SQL queries to DB. Something like this `spring.jpa.show-sql = true`. And check them out.